# Generating Form Fields from XML Tags

Tags: php, xml, forms, dynamic, input

I'm trying to figure out a way to utilize a PHP script that will:

1. Open an XML document when a link to
   that document is clicked (from an
   HTML page).
2. Scan the XML document for tags.
3. Create an HTML form with input
   fields based on the tags.
4. Post the input data back to the XML
   within the tags (when form is
   submitted) and        print the XML
   to HTML.

So, if I had an XML file that went like this:

```
<profile>
Hello, my name is <name></name>.  I am <age></age> years old.  I live in <place></place>
</profile>
```

Upon clicking a link to that file, PHP would generate a form like so:

```
<form> 
Name:
Age:
Place:
</form>
```

Then upon completing and submitting the form (let's say the person is Joel, 25, from Boston), the following would be written to the screen:

Hello, my name is Joel. I am 25 years old.  I live in Boston.

Any code or points to good tutorials would be appreciated.

THX

E.

Answer (score 2):

You should use XSLT for this..

With browser:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<profile>
Hello, my name is <name></name>.  I am <age></age> years old.  I live in <place></place>
</profile>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="profile">
        <form>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <label>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>: 
                    <input name="{name()}" type="text" />
                </label>
                <br />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </form>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<form>
    <label>name: <input type="text" name="name"></label><br />
    <label>age: <input type="text" name="age"></label><br />
    <label>place: <input type="text" name="place"></label><br />
</form>
```

There is an xsl extension for php you can use.

Comment: Thank you for this, inf3rno; it is definitely a point in the right direction.

Comment: Brilliant! What a direct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your placeholders always take the form `<tag></tag>`, you can search using regular expressions or simple string searching, generate your form fields, then do a string find/replace on the original to get the merged version.  That might be easier than doing it through XML parsing methods, because the content between the XML tags will be parsed as content nodes.

For that matter, I would use a placeholder like `%Name%` or `$Name$` instead of an XML tag, because then you can just parse it with simple string matching methods, without interfering with the overall XML structure.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  I understand what you are saying as far as using place-holders instead of tags and will keep it in mind, however, regardless of which method I use, I do not know how to execute any of this.  I am not very familiar with PHP or its commands/functions.  So what I really need to know is where to start with the coding of this particular set of operations.

Comment: You could start with documentation: http://us2.php.net/xml, and http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Lets just assume that I've already spent a large amount of time searching through documentation (official and not-so) and (perhaps do to my own lack of creativity or intelligence) have not found a method to complete the specific set of tasks.  I'm trying to not waste any more time by asking if some could (not code for me, but perhaps use some language references) please explain how this process would work within a PHP executable.